# Check order in a tuple

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7

I'm getting a bunch of tuples with 5 numbers from 0 to 9. I want to check if the tuple is sorted in ascending or descending order ( i.e 12345 02455 97311). How could do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
if some_tuple == tuple(sorted(some_tuple, reverse=True)):
    # Order is Descending
elif some_tuple == tuple(sorted(some_tuple)):
    # Order is Ascending
else:
    # No order
```

Comment: Just remember to cast the tuple to list!

Comment: @jd1215 sorry i actually was test with list, as you can see edited answer :) Thanks for the feedback will update answer now ...

Comment: @jd1215: until the `tuple()` calls were added, this code *could not have worked for you*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes that's right but the idea does make sense

Answer (score 1):

Let's keep it simple and stupid.

```
# Returns 1 if ascending, -1 if descending and 0 if no order
def check_sorted(t):
  assert len(t) >= 2

  ascending =  t[1] > t[0]
  norm = lambda d : d if ascending else -d
  for i in range(2, len(t)):
    if norm(t[i] - t[i-1]) < 0:
       return 0
  return 1 if ascending else -1
```

Comment: You could make it `range(2, len(t))`.

Comment: In this case, simple and stupid is also more efficient. This is a O(N) solution vs. O(NlogN) for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest check is:

```
ascending = x[0] < x[-1]
```

This will only work if you know that:

- the elements are in one order or the other (i.e not (1,3,2))
- there are at least two element
- the elements do not all have the same value

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
def which_order(t):
    if tuple(sorted(t)) == t:
        return 'ascending'
    if tuple(sorted(t, reverse=True)) == t:
        return 'descending'
    return 'out-of-order'
```

Comment: They don't want to know if it's in either order, they want to detect which order it's in.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it.

Comment: thats what I want! Thanks